# Unity auto resolution failed ,able to build the file but no ads on build

Tags: gradle, dependencies, admob

I am unity beginner made my first game ,all was working good until i try to implement the damn google ads .I am using unity 2020.3and ad mobile sdk 6.1 .Upon import the auto resolution failed .

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sPkw8.jpg

Here are three errors

https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4fgB.jpg

```
    Gradle failed to fetch dependencies.

Failed to run 'H:\Unity\Practice\AdsTesting\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\gradlew.bat --no-daemon -b "H:\Unity\Practice\AdsTesting\Temp\PlayServicesResolverGradle\PlayServicesResolver.scripts.download_artifacts.gradle" "-PANDROID_HOME=C:/Program Files/Unity/2020.3.18f1/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer\SDK" "-PTARGET_DIR=H:\Unity\Practice\AdsTesting\Assets\Plugins\Android" "-PMAVEN_REPOS=https://maven.google.com/" "-PPACKAGES_TO_COPY=com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.0.0" "-PUSE_JETIFIER=0" "-PDATA_BINDING_VERSION=4.0.1"'
stdout:
Unzipping C:\Users\Nofil Jamil Khan\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.1.1-bin\90y9l8txxfw1s2o6ctiqeruwn\gradle-5.1.1-bin.zip to C:\Users\Nofil Jamil Khan\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-5.1.1-bin\90y9l8txxfw1s2o6ctiqeruwn

stderr:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:163)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.unzip(Install.java:214)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.access$600(Install.java:27)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:74)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManager.access(ExclusiveFileAccessManager.java:65)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:48)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:128)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)

exit code: 1

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
Google.Logger:Log (string,Google.LogLevel) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.DHbeDZTDK0/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/Logger.cs:136)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log (string,Google.LogLevel) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CzMQNSaNjS/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1055)
GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver/<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey1:<>m__2 (GooglePlayServices.CommandLine/Result) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CzMQNSaNjS/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:451)
GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver/<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey1/<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey3:<>m__0 () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CzMQNSaNjS/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:564)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteNext () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.DHbeDZTDK0/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:486)
Google.RunOnMainThread:<ExecuteAllUnnested>m__1 () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.DHbeDZTDK0/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:536)
Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction (System.Action) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.DHbeDZTDK0/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:343)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAllUnnested (bool) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.DHbeDZTDK0/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:530)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.DHbeDZTDK0/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:512)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions ()
```

**Here is error 2**

```
Resolution failed

Failed to fetch the following dependencies:
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.0.0


UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
Google.Logger:Log (string,Google.LogLevel) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.DHbeDZTDK0/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/Logger.cs:136)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log (string,Google.LogLevel) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CzMQNSaNjS/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1055)
GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver:LogMissingDependenciesError (System.Collections.Generic.List`1<string>) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CzMQNSaNjS/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:95)
GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver/<DoResolutionUnsafe>c__AnonStorey8:<>m__1 (System.Collections.Generic.List`1<Google.JarResolver.Dependency>) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CzMQNSaNjS/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:912)
GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver/<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey1:<>m__0 () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CzMQNSaNjS/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:375)
GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver/<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey1:<>m__2 (GooglePlayServices.CommandLine/Result) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CzMQNSaNjS/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:454)
GooglePlayServices.GradleResolver/<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey1/<GradleResolution>c__AnonStorey3:<>m__0 () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CzMQNSaNjS/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/GradleResolver.cs:564)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteNext () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.DHbeDZTDK0/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:486)
Google.RunOnMainThread:<ExecuteAllUnnested>m__1 () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.DHbeDZTDK0/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:536)
Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction (System.Action) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.DHbeDZTDK0/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:343)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAllUnnested (bool) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.DHbeDZTDK0/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:530)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.DHbeDZTDK0/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:512)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions ()
```

**Here is error 3**

```
Resolution Failed.

Resolution failed

Failed to fetch the following dependencies:
com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:20.0.0


UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
Google.Logger:Log (string,Google.LogLevel) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.DHbeDZTDK0/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/Logger.cs:136)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver:Log (string,Google.LogLevel) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CzMQNSaNjS/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1055)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver/<ResolveUnsafe>c__AnonStorey9:<>m__0 (bool,string) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CzMQNSaNjS/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1913)
GooglePlayServices.PlayServicesResolver/<ResolveUnsafe>c__AnonStorey9:<>m__4 () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.CzMQNSaNjS/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/AndroidResolver/src/PlayServicesResolver.cs:1980)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteNext () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.DHbeDZTDK0/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:486)
Google.RunOnMainThread:<ExecuteAllUnnested>m__1 () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.DHbeDZTDK0/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:536)
Google.RunOnMainThread:RunAction (System.Action) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.DHbeDZTDK0/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:343)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAllUnnested (bool) (at Z:/tmp/tmp.DHbeDZTDK0/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:530)
Google.RunOnMainThread:ExecuteAll () (at Z:/tmp/tmp.DHbeDZTDK0/third_party/unity/unity_jar_resolver/source/VersionHandlerImpl/src/RunOnMainThread.cs:512)
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions ()
```

Now build is succeeded even with all these errors but problem is that i m able to see ads in unity editor but not in build

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjWD0.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Km2nB.jpg

please help me I am banging my head for a week now ,did all solutions on net that are there even did fresh installation of unity

Answer (score 0):

So if for any one who stumbled upon here , I solved it by

**1.I accidentally copied some files in user C:\Users\Nofil Jamil Khan.gradle\wrapper\dists**

*I deleted 5.1.1. bin and restarted my unity*

imported 6.1 plugin again in unity and resolution worked!!!

The next big problem was ads not working when app builds so clearly resolution failed was big issue .when i solved it .

ads very not working ,But they started working as soon as i tested out few small test projects .then i moved to project where the problem arised and found it i have custom key in key manager .***I uncheck custom key and ads start showing ,when i enabled custom key and added new key .the ads were still working but not working with older keys*** .Still dont know what was issue but this is all the issue i have .Make sure to keep the recommended options in unity preferences in in external tools

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).